# Downgrade to PHP 5.3

Tags: php, php-5.3

I've got a line of code that I need to get working in PHP 5.3.3.
I cannot upgrade the PHP version.

The error is in the last line below with the ::class property

> (unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$').

The context is:

```
abstract class E
{

    public static function validate($value)
    {
        $reflector = new ReflectionClass(static::class);
```

Is there any way to get this to work in PHP 5.3.3?

Comment: "I cannot upgrade the PHP version." You should try to fix that problem instead of this one.

Comment: 5.3.3 probably didn't have abstract classes, try changing it to just `class E`

Answer (score 0):

`::class` constant on classes has been introduced in PHP 5.5. The equivalent of `static::class` in PHP < 5.5 would be `get_called_class()`, so the faulty line in your code should look like this:

```
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
```

Comment: So, relatedly this code gives unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR error.  Is there a similar fix?

$request['order'] = $this->maybeSetKey($request['order'], 'date_time_created', (new \DateTime($builder->getOrderCreateDate()))->format(\DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED));

Comment: Is that line in the same method? There's no `$this` in static methods. You'll have to make `maybeSetKey` static and call it with `self::maybeSetKey()`.

Comment: No, different method. I'm seeing this code for the first time (not mine).

Comment: I don't know then. There's an excellent post on SO that helps solve parse errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them. Since I helped you with the original problem, please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: I am trying, but since I am new it says it records it but doesn't show it(?)